# $f$ has countably many fixed points .Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Consider  the  function  $f : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ defined  by $f(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x}$ , for all $ x \in (0, \infty)$ .

Pick  correct  statement(s)  from the  following

$1.$ $f$  has  countably  many fixed points.

$2.$ For  any $a >0$ , the  restriction map $ f |_{(a, \infty) } : (a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ has  infinitely  many fixed points.

$3.$The  restriction  map  $f |_{(0,1]}:(0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $  has   finitely  many fixed points.

$4.$ The  restriction map $ f |_{[1, \infty) } : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ has  no fixed points.

**My attempts**:

Both options $1$ and $2$ are correct in my opinion
because  $\sin \frac{1}{x}$     intersect $x$ at countably infinite  points.

Am i right ?

Comment: It does have countably many fixed points, but where are they?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Actually , I don't know .I just used my logic .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not. Note that $\sin(1/x)$ oscillates infinitely many times in the interval $(0,\infty)$ but it only does so finitely many times in any interval bounded away from zero. In particular, if $a>1$, the restriction in question ***never*** has a fixed point. *(While there are infinitely many intersections, you missed that **where** they are matters too!)*

Hence, $(2)$ is certainly not correct, while $(4)$ is. Both are obvious from the graph:

[image]

$(1)$ merits a proper argument of such. While you do know infinitely many fixed points exist, how do you know if it is a countable number? (After all, $f(x) = x$ trivially has uncountably many fixed points.)

Answer (score 1):

PrincessEev's answer is helpful, but not complete because as she mentions (1) requires a proper argument. Here is one showing countable fixed points:

You want to find cardinality of the set of solutions of $\sin t = \frac{1}{t}$ where I put $t = \frac{1}{x}$. Now suppose I label each half wave by a number i.e. Consider the sets $\cup_n A_n$ where $A_n = (n\pi, (n+1)\pi]$. Clearly the number of $A_n$ are countable, and you can formally show that the number of solutions of $\sin t = \frac{1}{t}$ lying in $A_n$ for any $n$ is atmost $2$, hence the number of fixed points is countable.